# Give an example of two different metrics on $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose restrictions to the $x$-axis are equal.

Tags: functions, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Give an example of two different metrics on $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose restrictions to the $x$-axis are equal.

Consider the two metrics $d_2$ and $d_1$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ where $d_2$ denotes the usual Euclidean distance and $d_1$ denotes the "taxicab" metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Namely, $d_1(x,y)=|x_2-x_1|+|y_2-y_1|$.

Restricting $d_2$ to the $x$-axis gives us,
$$d_2((x_1,0),(x_2,0))=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(0-0)^2}=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2}=|x_2-x_1|$$

Similarly, restricting $d_1$ to the $x$-axis yields,
$$d_1((x_1,0),(x_2,0))=|x_2-x_1|+|y_2-y_1|=|x_2-x_1|+0=|x_2-x_1|$$

Hence, $d_2$ and $d_1$ are equivalent when restricted to the $x$-axis.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct. Additionally, note that the same proof shows that all metrics induced by $L^p$ norms are equal when restricted to $x$-axis for all finite $p$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof must be edited somewhere else, but they're just a typo. **No logical flaw in your proof.**

These three things only need to be fixed like this(when $x=(x_1,x_2), y=(y_1,y_2)$).

$$
d_1(x,y)=|x_2-x_1|+|y_2-y_1|\Rightarrow d_1(x,y)=|y_1-x_1|+|y_2-x_2|\\
d_2(x,0)\Rightarrow d_2((x_1,0),(x_2,0))\\
d_1(x,0)\Rightarrow d_1((x_1,0),(x_2,0))
$$

Comment: Makes sense. Obviously the number 0 is not an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$!

Comment: @pyridoxal_trigeminus Yeah. Your miss are only several typo.